# using a quote bracket for require in ns definitiion

Tags: clojure

When using require, I need to use a quote before the left bracket but when I use ns with :require I can don't have to use the quote. Why is that?

```
(ns foo)
(ns user)
(require '[foo :as f])                ;; quote
(ns bar (:require [foo :refer :all])) ;; no quote
```

I am aware of the quote to not evaluate an expression in front of parenthesis but not entirely sure why the quote is needed in front of brackets since they are not expressions so nothing should be evaluated.

Comment: `[foo :refer :all]` and `[foo :as f]` are both expressions, even `42` is an expression (self-evaluating of course in this case)

Comment: Sorry, i still don't grok it. [1 2 3] returns [1 2 3] but (1 2 3) returns a ClassCastException. I need '(1 2 3) so why not the quote on the array? It seems that quote or no quote the array expression always returns an array. Why would I then have to use the quote in require?

Comment: because when you quote an expression, the symbols in that expression are not evaluated, `'no-such-thing` returns a valid symbol, `no-such-thing` will throw an error (unless you have previously bound that symbol with def or let etc.). I'm updating my answer below to include this part of the rationale, which I kind of skipped.

Comment: Thanks. The binding part is what I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `require` symbols that aren't bound in your namespace - the `'` before the vector (or just the `'` in an example like `(require 'clojure.string)` where you don't use any of the options) prevents an error caused by using a symbol that is unbound.

`ns` is a macro, that uses the `:require` portion of its body to build a call to `require`. Macros are allowed to decide which input is evaluated vs. left as the literal input, so you don't use `'` with the `ns` macro.